# Getting the Original Variable Name from a Concatenated Matrix [MATLAB]

Tags: matlab

I'm working on a personal project and I've kinda hit a wall. I made many variables that have a values that make a 1x5 vector. Ultimately, I want to make a matrix with these variables (so if I put 13 of these variables, the end matrix will be a 13x5). That part isn't the problem.

What I am having trouble with is that I want the user to be able to see the individual variables in the matrix based on their corresponding values.

Here's an example:

```
Bob = [5 9]

Joe = [6 0]

Sue = [5 6]

Mary = [6 1]

Bill = [4 8]

Names = [Bob;Joe;Sue;Mary;Bill]
```

Names is a 5x2 matrix with the VALUES of each of the variables. What I want is some way to reverse this process, some way to be able to get the original variable name from the Names matrix. If possible, I would like to take this a step further and possibly get to a point where if I, say, type `Names(1,:)`, I get `"Bob"` rather than `[5 9]`.

Of further note, all the variables that I am using have a unique vector value so that it could be specifically denoted by the specific value.

Answer (score 0):

You could represent your data as a struct `s` and then use `cell2mat(struct2cell(s))` to get its matrix representation, and `fieldnames(s)` to get the names. For example:

```
s.Bob = [5 9];
s.Joe = [6 0];
s.Sue = [5 6];
s.Mary = [6 1];
s.Bill = [4 8];
fNames = fieldnames(s);
Names = cell2mat(struct2cell(s))
```

Results with:

```
Names =

     5     9
     6     0
     5     6
     6     1
     4     8
```

Typing:

```
fNames(1,:)
```

Results with:

```
ans = 

    'Bob'
```

Typing:

```
fNames(3,:)
```

Results with:

```
ans = 

    'Sue'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a recent version of MATLAB, you could use a `table` to do this. You'll need column vectors though, something like this:

```
Bob = Bob';
Joe = Joe';
...
table(Bob, Joe...)
```

See the doc for more: http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-a-table.html